# Mod p cohomology operations and homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy-theory

It is well-known that "the $p$-torsion in the stable homotopy groups of spheres originate in $\pi_{2p}(S^3)$, but how can I prove this for odd primes?

My idea would be to show that the mod $p$-cohomology operation $P^1$ acts non-trivially on the cohomology of the cofiber of a map $S^{2p}\rightarrow S^3$ that generates the $p$-torsion subgroup. As $P^1$ commutes with the suspension this would prove the result, but how to prove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is here is to not start with the cofiber, but rather to find it naturally inside another space, where it sits in a manner in which we can easily understand it. Details are as follows.

Consider the infinite complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$. Then the integral cohomology ring $H^*\mathbb{C}P^\infty\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a polynomial algebra on a degree $2$ class $x$. It follows that $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ has a cell structure $S^2\cup e^4\cup\dots\cup e^{2n}\cup\dots$, and that the inclusion $S^2\cong\mathbb{C}P^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}P^\infty$ induces an isomorphism on $H^2$. Moreover, after reduction mod $p$ we have $\mathcal{P}^1x=x^p\in H^{2p}(\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_p)$ by the properties of the Steenrod squares.

The point is that after suspension we have a map $S^3\hookrightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ which induces an isomorphism on $H^3$ with any coefficients and we know exactly how $\mathcal{P}^1$ acts on the domain of the induced homomorphism. As it stands it seems difficult to get much out of this, but it turns out that there is a lot we can do if we introduce an odd prime $p$ and consider the same problem after localisation at this prime. If you are unfamiliar with this process I will be happy to supply some references, but the main idea is that we are formally inverting the action of every other prime $p'\neq p$ as a multiplication operator on $\pi_*$ and $H_*$. It is a celebrated result that that this algebraic construction can actually be realised topologically.

Now $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is a homotopy-associative, homotopy-commutative H-space, since it identifies homotopically with both $BS^1$ and $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$. Let $\mu:\mathbb{C}P^\infty\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ be its multiplication. In the sequel I will be following Cohen's paper *Splitting Certain Suspensions Via Self-Maps*.

At this stage we Introduce the *odd* prime $p$ and choose a mod $p$ primitive root of unity $k$. We use this to form the map $f_k$ as the composition

$$f_k:\mathbb{C}P^\infty\xrightarrow{\Delta}\prod^k\mathbb{C}P^\infty\xrightarrow{\mu(\mu\times1)\dots(\mu\times1\times\dots\times 1)}\mathbb{C}P^\infty$$

where the first map is the iterated diagonal. We know for dimensional reasons that in cohomology we have $\mu^*x=x\otimes 1+1\otimes x$ and an easy calculation shows us that

$$f^*_k(x^n)=k^n\cdot x^n.$$

Now with $k$ fixed as above we define for each $j=1,\dots,p-1$ a map $\theta_j:\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\rightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ by

$$g_j=\Sigma f_k-k^j$$

where the sum is taken using the suspension comultiplciation of $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, and $k^j$ is the map which is $k^j$ times the identity (if you identify $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty=S^1\wedge \mathbb{C}P^\infty$, then this map is just the wedge $k^j\wedge 1$ of the degree map on $S^1$). Another easy check shows us that

$$g_j^*(\sigma x^n)=(k^n-k^j)\sigma x^n$$

where $\sigma x^n\in H^{2n+1}\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is the image of $x^n$ under the suspension isomorphism. The upshot of this is that after reduction mod $p$ we have that $(k^n-k^j)\equiv 0\mod p$ if and only if $(n-j)\equiv 0\mod p-1$

Finally we form a last set of maps $\theta_j:\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\rightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$, for $j=1,\dots,p-1$ by setting

$$\theta_j=g_1\circ\dots\circ\widehat g_j\circ\dots\circ g_{p-1}$$

where the hat indicates that the map is *omitted* from the composition. Again you can calculate what each of these maps do on cohomology, but it is easy to see from our previous comments that $\theta_j$ induces multiplication by a mod $p$ unit in degrees congruent to $j$ mod $p-1$ and the $0$-homomorphism in all other degrees.

Therefore we should consider the decomposition

$$H^*\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\cong \bigoplus_{j=1,\dots,p-1} M_j$$

where $M_j$ contains all the cohomology in degrees congruent to $j$ mod $p-1$. Then $im(\theta_j^*)\subseteq M_j$. The point is that if we now consider cohomology with mod $p$ coefficients, then $im(\theta_j^*)=M_j$, since in the degrees in which $\theta_j^*$ is non-zero it is just multiplication by a mod $p$ unit. What we actually need to do, however, is to consider coefficients in the $p$-local integers $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$. Then the map

$$\bigoplus_{j=1,\dots,p-1}\theta_j^* :H^*(\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\xrightarrow{\cong} \bigoplus_{j=1,\dots,p-1} M_j$$

realises the previous isomorphism.

The point of all this is that $\theta_j^*$ is induced by an actual map of *spaces*, and is just not some abstract module decomposition. Therefore, for each $j=1,\dots,p-1$ we let $K_j$ be the mapping telescope

$$K_j=Tel\big(\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\xrightarrow{\theta_j}\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\xrightarrow{\theta_j} \dots\big).$$

Then calculating with $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-cohomology we have that $H^*(K_j;\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\cong M_j$. For each $j$ there is a map $f_j:\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\rightarrow K_j$ induced by including $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ as the first space in the telescope, and when we form the map

$$f:\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\xrightarrow{\oplus f_j}\bigvee_{j=1,\dots,p-1}K_j,$$

the sum once again being formed using the suspension coordinate, we find that

$$f^*:\bigoplus_{j=1,\dots,p-1}M_j\cong H^*(\bigvee_{j=1,\dots,p-1}K_j;\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})\xrightarrow{\cong} H^*(\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}_{(p)})$$

is exactly the isomorphism we wrote down abstractly above.

Now in the integral world this doesn't say much, but after localisation at $p$, we can appeal to the Whitehead theorem, since $f$ is a map between simply-connected spaces which induces an isomorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-cohomology. Thus $f$ is a p-local homotopy equivalence

$$\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty\simeq \bigvee_{j=1,\dots,p-1}K_j,$$

and we see that localised at the odd prime $p$, the suspension $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ splits as a wedge-sum of $p-1$-pieces, whose cohomology we can easily understand.

Now let us return to the problem at hand. We'll start with $\mathbb{C}P^p$, suspend and include into $\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^\infty$. Then for cellular reasons the homotopy equivalence we've just written down gives us that

$$\Sigma\mathbb{C}P^p\simeq S^3\cup e^{2p+1}\vee S^5\vee S^7\vee\dots\vee S^{2p-1}$$

since these are the only cells of the $K_j$ in these dimensions (to see this just study their cohomological counterparts $M_j$).

Now the first wedge summand is a 2-cell complex formed by attaching a $(2p+1)$-cell to $S^3$ by a map $\alpha:S^{2p}\rightarrow S^3$. Since the Steenrod operations commute with suspension we get

$$\mathcal{P}^1(\sigma x)=\sigma(\mathcal{P}^1x)=\sigma x^p,$$

and it follows from this that $\alpha$ must be non-trivial. Hence there is an element $\alpha\in\pi_{2p}S^3$ which is non-trivial and detected by $\mathcal{P}^1$.